# google-translate api returns SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-translate, google-translate-api

I used a simple code to translate strings using [@iamtraction/google-translate](https://github.com/iamtraction/google-translate)

```
const translate = require('@iamtraction/google-translate');

module.exports = function({ string, from, to }) {

    return new Promise(resolve => { 

        run();

        async function run() {
            try {
                const res = await translate(string, { from, to });
                return resolve(res.text);
            } catch(err) {
                console.log(err);
                run();
            }
        }

    });

}
```

and I used the above function as:

```
const bigTranslation = await googleTranslator({ string: 'It looks like we’ll have to stand', from: 'en', to: 'es' });

return console.log(bigTranslation);
```

It worked perfectly till hours ago but now I get this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
> at JSON.parse ()
> at consumeEnd (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Server\node_modules\undici\lib\api\readable.js:237:20)
> at BodyReadable. (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Server\node_modules\undici\lib\api\readable.js:219:7)
> at BodyReadable.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at BodyReadable.emit (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Server\node_modules\undici\lib\api\readable.js:66:18)
> at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)

Why This is happening ?

Comment: That error means that the response is in HTML/XML format, not JSON. Use the network tab of devtools to debug what the response is - most likely it's an error message.

Comment: data format is not in correct json format so it give this error "in JSON at position 0"